# Firebase getting user id value. (iOS objective C)

Tags: firebase

I'm wondering how do I get the user_id value from a currently authenticated user, so when I'm writing a new record I can reference the user who wrote it.

My data is structured as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxcO4.jpg

Comment: Use `FirebaseReference.authData`, per [https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/user-auth.html](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/user-auth.html).

Answer (score 1):

If someone finds this post and is still looking for an answer:

```
[FIRAuth auth].currentUser.uid;
```

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being my solution, seems to work fine.

```
A0SimpleKeychain *keychain = [[Application sharedInstance] store];

A0UserProfile *profile = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:              [keychain dataForKey:@"profile"]];

NSLog(@"user: %@",profile.userId);
```

Comment: Again, Rob's answer would be more appropriate. There's nothing to unpack here and no need to start playing with the keychain. Just grab it from the authData returned on successful auth ops.